# Any way to give a file descriptor to a child process, without closing it?

Tags: rust

The [`Stdio`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html) type implements `FromRawFd`, which lets me build one out of any file descriptor. (In my case, I want to use pipes.) That's exactly what I need, but my problem is that the `stdin()`/`stdout()`/`stderr()` methods take their `Stdio` argument by value. That means that when the `Command` object goes out of scope, all its fd's get closed. Is there any way to give an fd to a child process sort of by reference, so that it's still available in the parent process after the child is done? Right now I've settled for just calling `libc::dup()` for each child, which doesn't seem great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no better solution, alas. However, the correct solution would be a `Command::into_io(self) -> (Option<StdIo>, Option<StdIo>, Option<StdIo>)` method that deconstructs the `Command` to return stdin, stdout and stderr, if available.

I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32394) to add that function.